# How to do operations between two large dataframe with same indexes efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have these dataframes(Zcp,Qp(0),Sc(0)):

```
         i   hs4    1995   ...        2013        2014        2015
0       004  0101   0.000  ...     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1       004  0102   0.000  ...     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2       004  0104   0.000  ...     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
3       004  0105   1.548  ...     0.000000    0.000000    4.083000
4       004  0106  16.839  ...    38.298000   72.338000   83.931000
...     ...   ...     ...  ...          ...         ...         ...
225765  894  9702   0.000  ...    12.961000    0.000000    0.000000
225766  894  9703   9.173  ...    17.804779   13.400000   16.979594
225767  894  9704   0.000  ...     0.000000   36.000000    0.000000
225768  894  9705  42.241  ...  1224.378276  164.680333  435.218955
225769  894  9706   0.000  ...   113.253000   18.656000    0.000000

      hs4      1995      1996   ...     2013      2014      2015
0     0101  3.811149  3.780993  ...  3.781750  3.757388  3.755313
1     0102  3.788707  3.859526  ...  3.568241  3.618460  3.594909
2     0103  4.021830  4.014036  ...  3.901071  3.902159  3.879100
3     0104  3.580394  3.553510  ...  3.745742  3.761684  3.840236
4     0105  3.717383  3.734866  ...  3.731004  3.686321  3.654970
...    ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
1236  9702  3.886697  4.089046  ...  3.913331  3.914801  3.973163
1237  9703  3.725988  3.749821  ...  3.710488  3.673745  3.790359
1238  9704  3.620836  3.612135  ...  3.692998  3.684579  3.635194
1239  9705  3.656766  3.696438  ...  3.621836  3.604557  3.578214
1240  9706  3.782179  3.840093  ...  3.732887  3.682156  3.729555

      i      1995      1996    ...     2013      2014      2015
0    004  2.498013  2.709929   ...  3.251985  3.220664  3.222372
1    008  3.812630  4.111502   ...  3.683572  3.881263  4.087454
2    012  1.521194  1.565437   ...  1.206792  1.315348  1.383676
3    016 -0.000000 -0.000000   ...  2.604784  2.631275  2.639739
4    020  3.729594  3.946768   ...  2.133141  1.869886  3.441653
..   ...       ...       ...   ...       ...       ...       ...
219  876  2.278855  2.578395   ...  2.224869  1.905085  2.255480
220  882  0.868912  1.464654   ...  2.585345  3.209558  2.745666
221  887  0.698383  0.746020   ...  1.751111  1.761297  2.287436
222  891  4.737027  5.155827   ... -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
223  894  1.620051  1.988590   ...  2.309357  1.737125  1.992602
```

Where i represent the country(c), hs4 the product(p) and for every year from 1995 to 2015 there are these values.
What i have to do is this:

[image: formulas]

I'm at the beginning because i can't find a efficient and fast way to associate the same code for i and hs4 and do the operations i need. I was trying in this mode but it's really too slow and it's only for the multiplication and the summation:

```
for row1 in df.itertuples(index=False):
    for row2 in q.itertuples(index=False):
    datas1 = df.loc[row1._2:row1._22]
    datas2 = q.loc[row2._1:row2._21]
    if row1.hs4==row2.hs4:
        df.loc[row1._2:row1._22]=datas1*datas2
        Df = df.groupby(['i']).agg(np.sum).reset_index()
```

(With df.itertuples '1995'...'2015' becomes '_2'...'_22', don't know why).
Then I should do the division and the summation with logarithm, maybe updating Qp and Sc every cycle.
I've searched some helps in the web but haven't found the right answer.